# How to prevent users with "edit_others_posts" capability from editing admin posts

Tags: user-roles, capabilities

I have some posts that author is *`Administrator`* and some other posts that author is *`Editor`*

After logging in as *`Editor`*, I can edit *`Administrator`* posts. I would like to prevent this.

I find some information about filters like `user_has_cap` and `map_meta_cap` but i'm not sure it's right direction. Maybe I'm digging too deep and a simpler solution is nearby?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`map_meta_cap` is the correct filter to use.

When WordPress checks whether you have permission to edit a post it checks `edit_post`. If you are the author of that post, that is mapped to the `edit_posts` capability, but if you're not it is mapped to `edit_others_posts`. You can use this filter to add the additional condition that Editors cannot edit posts by Administrators, even if they have `edit_others_posts`.

In this example, when WordPress checks `edit_post`, if the post author was an administrator, then the current user also needs to be an administrator to edit it:

```
add_filter(
    'map_meta_cap',
    function( $required_caps, $cap, $user_id, $args ) {
        if ( 'edit_post' === $cap) {
            $post = get_post( $args[0] );

            if ( $post && user_can( $post->post_author, 'administrator' ) ) {
                $required_caps[] = 'administrator';
            }
        }

        return $required_caps;
    },
    10,
    4
);
```